# How to access static constants with a string variable

Tags: php

I've got my class:

```
class UserLevels {
    const CustomerService = 3;
    const Development = 6;
    const Accounts = 9;
    const Admin = 12;
}
```

And I can access it from other classes with `UserLevels::Development`, for example.

But instead, let's say I had a variable, `$x = 'Development'` -- how could I use that to access the same value?

Comment: Seems so, I'll test it. thank you

Comment: Without reflection, it is possible to check if a constant is defined, also within a class, using defined() https://www.php.net/defined . And get the value using constant() https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php